# Deleting an item from a list using the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm new to web development. I'm learning JS, and while playing around with some code, I made a simple to-do app with only using the DOM.

I'm having trouble getting the logic right to delete an item from a list. I'm traversing doms and using methods like; parentNode, removeChild to do so. I previously tested another way of deleting the last item from a list using n:last-child selector, but I can't seem to find a way to remove an item individually.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>grapes<span><button class="removeBtn">Remove</button></span></li>
  <li>amethyst<span><button class="removeBtn">Remove</button></li>
  <li>lavender<span><button class="removeBtn">Remove</button></li>
  <li>plums<span><button class="removeBtn">Remove</button></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
const   listDiv         = document.querySelector('.listDiv'),
        hideBtn         = document.querySelector('#hideBtn'),
        addItemBtn      = document.querySelector('button.addItemBtn'),
        addItemInput    = document.querySelector('input.addItemInput'),
        removeListBtn   = document.querySelector('button.removeListBtn'),
        removeToDo      = document.querySelectorAll('.removeBtn'),
        li              = document.querySelectorAll('li'),
        list            = document.querySelector('ul');

//adding an item to list
    addItemBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let list = document.querySelector('ul'),
            newItem = document.createElement('li');
        newItem.textContent = addItemInput.value;
        if (addItemInput.value !== ''){
           list.appendChild(newItem);
            addItemInput.value = ''; 
        }
    })


//remove last item
    removeListBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let list = document.querySelector('ul'),
        lastItem = document.querySelector('li:last-child');
        list.removeChild(lastItem);
    })


//delete a list item 
    removeToDo.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        list.removeChild(li);
    });
```

I know it looks terrible, but I'm just looking to sharpen up my skills with the dom and find ways to achieve the delete button functionality. Any suggestions?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns `NodeList`. It doesn't have `addEventListener` you need to loop it and add click listner to each button or use event delegation since you are adding more rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Iterate over *all* the buttons
2. Add event listener
3. Traverse up to the list container and remove respective child on click

```js
var deletes = document.querySelectorAll('.removeBtn')
// Iterate all nodes
deletes.forEach(btn => {
  // Attach event listener. Note to preserve the button this-reference
  // by using the non-shorthand function
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var li = this.parentNode
    li.remove()
  })
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one<button class="removeBtn">Delete</button>
    <li>two<button class="removeBtn">Delete</button>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks for your help E!

Answer (score 0):

Explanation is in the comments:

```
const listDiv = document.querySelector('.listDiv'),
  hideBtn = document.querySelector('#hideBtn'),
  addItemBtn = document.querySelector('button.addItemBtn'),
  addItemInput = document.querySelector('input.addItemInput'),
  //it is a NodeList
  removeToDos = document.querySelectorAll('.removeBtn'),  
  //list of items, 
  ul = document.querySelector('ul');


//because we have NodeList we have iterate over its values
removeToDos.forEach(function(removeTodo){
    //add event listener on each dom element
    removeTodo.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(removeTodo.parentNode.parentNode);
    //get a reference to li closest to the button clicked
    const li =  removeTodo.parentNode.parentNode;
    //remove child by: parent.removeChild(child); syntax
    ul.removeChild(li);
  });
});
```

also fix the last li in HTML by adding closing span tag:

```
<li>plums<span><button class="removeBtn">Remove</button></span></li>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bakhtiiar! Just curious on why using parentNode twice? Is it because were selecting the btn and the btn parent is its 'li' and the second parentNode selects the 'li' and trace it up to its 'ul'?

Comment: because we starting from button element then first going up to span element then after to li element which is an element we are planning to delete. That is why we are using it two times. Please mark this as an answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are planning to add items to the list I do recommend you to use event delegation. Naive implementation should work for your structure.

```js
const removeToDo      = document.querySelectorAll('.removeBtn'),
        list            = document.querySelector('ul');

// find closest el including el itself that matches selector
const closest = (el, selector) => {
  while(el && !el.matches(selector)) {
    el = el.parentNode
  }
  
  return el
}

// add event listener to the list itself once once
list.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if(target.matches('.removeBtn')) {
    closest(target, 'li').remove()
  }
  
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>grapes<span><button class="removeBtn">Remove</button></span></li>
  <li>amethyst<span><button class="removeBtn">Remove</button></span></li>
  <li>lavender<span><button class="removeBtn">Remove</button></span></li>
  <li>plums<span><button class="removeBtn">Remove</button></span></li>
</ul>
```