# javascript - remove element from div when button inside is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `div` that looks like this:

```
<div id="contact-segments">
    <div class="contact-segment-item doesnt-include">
        <div class="segment-content pull-left" style="width: 80%">
            <p>LOL</p>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a href="your link here">
                <i class="white-segment-icon fa fa-times"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Whenever someone presses an add button, I add another `contact-segment-item div` to the `contact-segments div` through JavaScript with this function:

```
function createUserSegment(tags) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = 'contact-segment-item includes'
    div.innerHTML = "<div class='segment-content pull-left' style='width: 80%''> <p>" + tags + "</p> </div> <div class='pull-right'> <a href='your link here'> <i class='white-segment-icon  fa fa-times'></i></a> </div>";
    document.getElementById("contact-segments").appendChild(div);
}
```

As you can see, the divs that are getting added through JavaScript have an `a` tag that shows a button with an "x".

How can I remove the `contact-segment-item` when the "x" is pressed inside of it?

Here's how each of them look so it's easier to picture.

I can link the "x" button click to javascript but how do I know which child of `contact-segments` to delete and also how do I get the `p` of it before it's deleted.

[image]
When the user presses the "x" on this `div`, I want to get the `p` or in this case `Woop!` so I can do something with it but then also delete that `contact-segment-item`

Thanks

Comment: Reminds me of this question from a few days ago https://stackoverflow.com/q/44887125/3951400

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

Comment: @E.Sundin If I make my "x" a button and add a listener like in that post and follow those instructions... How would I delete 2 `divs` out instead of the `div` surrounding the button? Also, how can I get the `p` before doing so?

Comment: You can walk and up and down the node tree by accessing `parentNode` and `querySelector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `.innerHTML` we nest nodes with `appendChild.` Finally for our close `i` button we add `onClick` event handler. We pass there our `div` node, and use `remove()` method to remove the node.

**EDIT:**

Added css.

Do not use `a` if your anchors only needs to delete your segments. For example use only `i` without wrapping `a` and add a `cursor: pointer` style to it.

See working example:

```js
function createUserSegment(tags){

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = 'contact-segment-item includes';
  
  var tagInfo = document.createElement("div");
  tagInfo.className = 'contact-segment-item__text';
  tagInfo.innerHTML = tags;
  
  var closeButton = document.createElement("i");
  closeButton.className = 'contact-segment-item__closeButton white-segment-icon fa fa-times';
  closeButton.onclick = function() {
    div.remove();
  };
  
  div.appendChild(tagInfo);
  div.appendChild(closeButton);
  

  document.getElementById("contact-segments").appendChild(div);

}
```

```css
#contact-segments {
  max-width:350px;
  width: 100%;
}

.contact-segment-item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00B792;
  border-radius: 8px;
  line-height: 40px;
  clear: both;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.contact-segment-item__anchor::after {
  clear: both;
}

.contact-segment-item__text {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}

.contact-segment-item__closeButton {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button id="add-new" onClick="createUserSegment('new one')">Add new segment</button>

<br/>

<div id="contact-segments">

</div>
```

Comment: This is great! Wow thank you so much. How can I put the `p` inner html and the close button side by side? It's now appearing one of the top of the other... I would like it to remain looking like my image. I really appreciate your help. Also, in the onclick, can I still access the `tags` of that instance? I need to remove it from an array.

Comment: you can add a `.className` property to `paragraph` like so `paragraph.className = 'inline-paragraph'` Then you can style it using css. `tags` param you pass to your function will be accessible inside `onclick`. Make sure `array` you mentioned is in proper `scope` eg. global scope.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Accept it if it is ok for you. I've added css to show you how you can style it. I've also replaced `p` width another `div`. Do not use `a` if your anchors only needs to delete your segment. For example use only `i` without wrapping `a` and add a `cursor: pointer` style.

Comment: Can you please modify to not include a? I only need to delete my segment. Thank you @loelsonk. Life saver! Marked as answer.

Comment: @Walker Glad I could help you. I've updated answer to not include `anchor` tag.

Comment: are you available by any chance? I have a quick question regarding html. How do we start a chat on stack overflow? Thanks!